# CSS "!important" doesn't seem to work

Tags: css

My CSS has , in the following order:

```
B, STRONG
{
    color: #333;
}
A
{
    color: #00ae9d !important;
    border-bottom: dotted 1px #00ae9d;
    text-decoration:none;
}
```

But when I hold a link, it comes up gray with green dots. What do I need to do so that bolded items come up dark gray, and linked bolded items come up green with dots? Is there a way to rank each rule?

Comment: And what's your HTML? Also: why uppercase? It's *valid*, yes, but goodness, it looks so very shouty. Interestingly Eric Meyer sort of [touched on this, earlier](https://twitter.com/meyerweb/status/314839078153629696)

Comment: The use of `!important` is actually superfluous in this case since your rules are being applied to different elements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The behavior will depend on the order that you're setting your tags

```
<b><a href="#">One</a></b>
```

is not the same as

```
<a href="#"><b>One</b></a>
```

Check [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xqKz9/)

Comment: This is correct. Try the > operator to catch both possibilities. See http://jsfiddle.net/xqKz9/3/. You could also use "A B" and "B A" but that would only apply to immediate children.

Comment: What I meant to say above was: You could also use "A B" and "B A" if there are going to be other tags between the B and A. A>B and B>A will work only when B is the immediate child of A and vice versa.

Answer (score 2):

to give color to a `<a>` you need to do follow LoVe HAte rule:

**L**`(link)`o**V**`(visited)`e **H**`(hover)`**A**`(active)`te

```
a:link {
 color: #00ae9d;
}
a:visited {
 color: #999;
}
a:hover {
 color: #900;
}
a:active {
 color: #555;
}
a:focus {
 color: #900;
}
```

off course you can group them, but you have to keep the same order.

```
a:link, a:visited {
 color: #00ae9d;
}
a:hover, a:active, a:focus {
 color: #900;
}
```

Comment: Just to add... you don't necessarily _need_ to apply rules to all the pseudo-classes (ie. follow the LoVe HAte rule) if you simply want to style the anchor the same in all states, which might be the case in the OP.